# SweetAlert2: How to get back values from react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert2

With `sweetalert2` now there is `sweetalert2-react-content`, that lets you use React components to show inside Swal.
It's good, but I can't seem to find how to get back values from that component.

For example, I have a component, that has two inputs.

```
MySwal.fire({
  html: <MyComponent />
}).then(value => {
  // how to get here my values from MyComponent??
});
```

I want get whether checkboxes are checked or not from that component.

I tried to have the state for those inputs and `onChangeHandler` in the component where I call `MySwal`. But that didn't seem to work at all, the checkboxes would not change.

In the previous version of this library there was `swal.setActionValue`, that seemed be what I need, but it doesn't work with the current `sweetlalert2` version.

To sum up, when I press OK on the prompt, I want to get the value in the promise, that would be set by the `MyComponent`.

[**DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/1qyrpn325l)

Comment: Can you create a small demo in code sandbox or jsfiddle?

Comment: @varit05, yep, put the demo in the question

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-react-content

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **preConfirm()** as per the documentation. From perConfirm we can pass custom values.

Please find this example :  https://codesandbox.io/s/kk2nv9nmy7

Comment: Have you tried it? It errors out. And secondly I don't really want to use document.getElementById in my Reactjs code.  And I have read about preConfirm and don't see how it fits in here. I mean, I do kind of, but not all the way. There is no connection really from the component.

Comment: @askerovlab Yes i tried but option.js not saved. Now check. And tell me whether you are using redux ?

Comment: I am. Not very comfortable with this solution though, because of the document.getElementById. I guess, maybe something with refs might work. It would be great if swal had possibility to put two inputs on the modal, and then I wouldn't need the component at all.

Comment: @askerovlab sweetheart is not exposing their childrens. we can use redux to communicate options component to your App component.

Answer (score 0):

The following trick should do the job:

```
let returnedValue;

MySwal.fire({
  html: <Options onChange={value => (returnedValue = value)} />
}).then(value => {
  console.log(returnedValue);
});
```

Long story short you could pass `onChange` callback to the component and use it for updating a variable which stores a value. It's not very pretty but it does the job.

You could find the full example here https://codesandbox.io/s/o1005xv1q

Comment: ..or even better you could use `preConfirm` like `preConfirm: () => returnedValue`